# Swing on OSX: How to Trap command-Q?

Tags: java, swing, macos

After [being convinced ("schooled") that Swing apps on Mac do look native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053555/java-on-all-platforms/2053587#2053587), I'm trying to make mine look as native as possible. Everything looks great, but when I hit <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> or do it from the menu, my `windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e)` is not firing on my main JFrame (if I exit in any other way, it does fire). How can I respond to the real Apple quit?

Comment: +1 for an interesting question that helped rock my naive notions of "write once, run anywhere." I guess that explains why Apple builds their own Java.

Comment: Thanks Carl. Few problems go by without me noting that it's Joel's concept of "leaky abstractions," yet again.

Comment: It's a bit like Godwyn's law.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The top voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2061318/8047) is excellent but just to fill in the "best way":

```
System.setProperty("apple.eawt.quitStrategy", "CLOSE_ALL_WINDOWS");
```

This will trigger the standard window closing callback event which should work really nicely for portable code.

As a result of the discussion below it seems that its crucial to do this really early in the app. I wrote this early in the static initializer of the main class before any UI code was executed.

Comment: isn't this the same as `Application.getApplication().setQuitStrategy(QuitStrategy.CLOSE_ALL_WINDOWS);`?

Comment: Yep. But it doesn't require access to the Application class which you wouldn't want for a portable app. Its one line of code instead of reflection.

Comment: @Yar: Sadly, they're _not_ the same with regard to `command-Q`; I've updated the [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30308671/230513) cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2061318/230513) to show a portable approach; elide the call to `enableOSXQuitStrategy()` to se the effect.

Comment: Damn you are correct. This just doesn't seem to be doable in a portable way without reflection! Thanks for the code!

Comment: Actually no. My test case was flawed. This worked for me both with the cmd-Q and the quit menu option. On which version of the JDK does cmd-Q not work?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog: I tested various combinations of Java 1.8.0_[45,60] on Mac OS X 10.[9,10,11]; your approach works as documented to send `WINDOW_CLOSING` when clicking the red close button but not via `command-Q` or the applicaiotn menu; I'd be happy to find I'm wrong! :-)

Comment: Odd, that's the exact version of Java I'm using too. I'm still on Yosemite maybe the OS version has something to do with that?

Comment: That explains it. I set it in my static initializer code before anything else.

Answer (score 16):

You can implement [`com.apple.eawt.ApplicationListener`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Java/Reference/1.5.0/appledoc/api/com/apple/eawt/ApplicationListener.html) and respond to the `Quit` event. An example may be found in the *Mac OS X Reference Library* example, [OSXAdapter](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/samplecode/OSXAdapter/Introduction/Intro.html).

Addendum: See [*Java for Mac OS X 10.6 Update 3 and 10.5 Update 8 Release Notes*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Java/JavaSnowLeopardUpdate3LeopardUpdate8RN/NewandNoteworthy/NewandNoteworthy.html) for information on deprecation, the redesigned `com.apple.eawt.Application` class, and the location of API documentation for the Apple Java extensions. Control-click or right-click on the `.jdk` file to `Show Package Contents`. You can browse the classes of [`com.apple.eawt`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/macosx/classes/com/apple/eawt) among the OpenJDK sources.

As shown in this complete [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30308671/230513), you can specify the desired 
`QuitStrategy`; a `WindowListener` will respond to <kbd>⌘Q</kbd>:

```
Application.getApplication().setQuitStrategy(QuitStrategy.CLOSE_ALL_WINDOWS);
```

As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33083356/230513), you can set the property from the command line

```
java -Dapple.eawt.quitStrategy=CLOSE_ALL_WINDOWS -cp build/classes gui.QuitStrategyTest
```

or early in the program, before posting any GUI events:

```
System.setProperty("apple.eawt.quitStrategy", "CLOSE_ALL_WINDOWS");
EventQueue.invokeLater(new QuitStrategyTest()::display);
```

[image]

Console, after <kbd>⌘Q</kbd>:

```
java.vendor: Oracle Corporation
java.version: 1.8.0_60
os.name: Mac OS X
os.version: 10.11
apple.eawt.quitStrategy: CLOSE_ALL_WINDOWS
java.awt.event.WindowEvent[WINDOW_CLOSING,opposite=null,oldState=0,newState=0] on frame0
```

Code:

```
package gui;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

/**
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/7457102/230513
 */
public class QuitStrategyTest {

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("QuitStrategyTest");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        });
        f.add(new JTextArea(getInfo()));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private String getInfo() {
        String[] props = {
            "java.vendor",
            "java.version",
            "os.name",
            "os.version",
            "apple.eawt.quitStrategy"
        };
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String prop : props) {
            sb.append(prop);
            sb.append(": ");
            sb.append(System.getProperty(prop));
            sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }
        System.out.print(sb);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("apple.eawt.quitStrategy", "CLOSE_ALL_WINDOWS");
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new QuitStrategyTest()::display);
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, I found that slightly after, but what do I do if I don't have the com.apple.eawt package? Or is it available on Windows too?

Comment: Awesome, it's all clear now. It calls all the classes dynamically. My code ended up being one line (plus Apple's class):         OSXAdapter.setQuitHandler(this, getClass().getDeclaredMethod("onClose", (Class[])null));

Comment: You have it exactly; I added some additional links to Apple's example for future reference.

Comment: It seems that since release 1.6 the class is deprecated. See: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Java/JavaSnowLeopardUpdate3LeopardUpdate8RN/NewandNoteworthy/NewandNoteworthy.html Redesigned eAWT

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty good question, and I must admit I don't have *the* answer. However, a couple years ago when I was working on a Java app and faced this problem, I solved it by registering a shutdown hook with the runtime that would do what I wanted the app to do before quitting. It's a heavy-handed solution but it worked. You can [take a look at my code](http://github.com/mdippery/snodes/blob/master/src/snodes/gui/GUIController.java#L151-161) and see if it helps.

Comment: interesting solution, it's not bad since I am writing the main method myself.

Answer (score 3):

I was originally seeing a 'access restriction' violation when trying to access the com.apple.eawt.Application and com.apple.eawt.* subclasses.

(Note: I'm programming on a MAC, using Eclipse, with Java 1.6 using Swing)

So I needed to modify my java build path to allow access to the apple subclasses by adding "com/apple/eawt/**" access rule.   After that this code below was able to compile and work for me:

```
//NOTE: This code only works for MAC OS.  If you run this on Windows
//the application never starts (so you literally need to remove this block of code)

import com.apple.eawt.*;
import com.apple.eawt.QuitHandler;

 Application a = Application.getApplication();
 a.setQuitHandler(new QuitHandler() {


@Override
public void handleQuitRequestWith(com.apple.eawt.AppEvent.QuitEvent qe, com.apple.eawt.QuitResponse qr) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int res = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, "Are you sure you want to exit the program?", "Quit ?", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

    if (res == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) 
        qr.performQuit();
    else
        qr.cancelQuit();

   }

});
```

Comment: Version of OSX? I think the access restriction issue is new.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting up <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> as an accelerator in your menu? Can you make your app respond to it?

I'm not positive, but I think this works in Linux and probably Windows with the equivalent <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F4</kbd>. My app responds to the "killing" keystroke, I process some cleanup code and then I do a programmatic `System.exit()`.

If you're "just" after graceful exit handling, you may also want to catch the `WindowEvent` `WINDOW_CLOSING`, where traditionally "are you sure?" stuff gets done.

Comment: won't work, because you can trip the menu item with your mouse too.

Comment: So what's wrong with that? It makes sense for your app to respond to the keystroke as well as the "Quit" menu item, and identically so.

Comment: Thanks for this first round. I do catch the WindowEvent. Works if I press the little red dot to close, but NOT if I use the "Quit MyApp    cmd-Q"...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not being clear. On OSX, one doesn't put the Quit menu item under file. It's part of the OS. All apps have it, like it or not.

Comment: Sure. The red dot closes the window but not the app - that's the Apple way. I really suggest you try putting cmd-Q in your menu before rejecting my answer out of hand.

Comment: Okay, you're right. But also I just found this "Apple provides functionality for this in the com.apple.eawt.* Java classes. The Application and ApplicationAdaptor classes provide a way to handle the Preferences, About, and Quit items."... don't know if that's right either. Easier to try your suggestion first.

Comment: Great, and I hope you get it working. But I do have to face the fact that I have too little Apple-specific Java experience to help you any further, so I'm going to throw in the towel with what grace I can muster. Good luck!

Comment: Cool, I'll upvote you so you'll have to live with this answer forever :)

Comment: I would comment on the QUESTION above, but then you'd never see it. Just wanted to respond to your comment in the Q and say that, "yes, it's true, Apple does kind of need their own Java implementation" because they're so heavy-handed with standard app behavior. Probably same fascism as runs the Apple Store. Not sure if it's morally okay, but the results are pretty interesting (usability of OS-wise). Anyway, I can see this is a pro-Mac comment, so I'll drop it before it offends....

Comment: Thank you, that's thoughtful. My answer is of little worth but I'm leaving it up to keep the discussion visible. Yes, Apple bullies the developer but the result is a very smooth user experience. Pros and cons to everything, I guess. I'm not sure it's the same in the Apple Store; as I understand it, much of what they do there is for the bottom line, not user convenience.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the link to [Java for Mac OS X 10.6 Update 3 and 10.5 Update 8 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Java/JavaSnowLeopardUpdate3LeopardUpdate8RN/NewandNoteworthy/NewandNoteworthy.html) I noticed that there is a section on **Default Quit Action**. This describes a system property to request that all windows are closed in response to the "Quit" menu item, which sounds like exactly what is needed? I have used this in my own application (using Info.plist to set the property on OS X only), and it seems to work as described. This would presumably only work on recent Java/OS X versions, but for those platforms seems like a neat solution, and doesn't require any code changes.

Comment: Thanks. @trashgod already took care of this in the addendum to his answer.

Comment: @Igor I don't know but all the regular events are called as expected.