# How to make "Enter" Key Behave like Submit on a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, client-server, jframe, key-bindings

I'm Building a Client/Server application.
and I want to to make it easy for the user at the Authentication Frame.

I want to know how to make <kbd>enter</kbd>-key submits the login and password to the Database (Fires the Action) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One convenient approach relies on [`setDefaultButton()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html#setDefaultButton%28javax.swing.JButton%29), shown in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456227/how-to-handle-events-from-keyboard-and-mouse-in-full-screen-exclusive-mode-in-jav/7457102#7457102) and mentioned in [*How to Use Key Bindings*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).

```
JFrame f = new JFrame("Example");
Action accept = new AbstractAction("Accept") {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // handle accept
    }
};
private JButton b = new JButton(accept);
...
f.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(b);
```

Comment: +1, I like this solution of adding the ActionListener to the button so that it doesn't matter which text field has focus when the enter key is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

Add an `ActionListener` to the password field component:

The code below produces this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));

    final JTextField user = new JTextField();
    final JTextField pass = new JTextField();

    user.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            pass.requestFocus();
        }
    });
    pass.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String username = user.getText();
            String password = pass.getText();

            System.out.println("Do auth with " + username + " " + password);
        }
    });
    frame.add(new JLabel("User:"));
    frame.add(user);

    frame.add(new JLabel("Password:"));
    frame.add(pass);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Why is the ActionListener only added to the password field? What if the user tabs back to the name field and users enter?

Comment: @camickr: ? There are two action listeners? And also, this was just an example how to use them..

Comment: It might be useful to re-factor this into a single, common `Action`. Also consider `JPasswordField`.

Comment: Oops, missed the second Action because the question was about how to submit the data on an Enter key (not on how to write an ActionLister). I was trying to stresss that the Action belongs to a button, not the text fields. The normal UI is to have a button (or two) to process data.