# Java Swing How to reset JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextpane

I am making a program where the user can type a string message into a JTextArea component, and press enter so that the message is sent, and then the JTextArea should be cleared and the caret position reset to 0.

```
    JTextArea userChatBox = new JTextArea();
    userChatBox.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
            if (e.getKeyCode()==10){
            //If key pressed is enter.  
                client.send(userChatBox.getText());
                userChatBox.setCaretPosition(0);
                userChatBox.setText("");

            }

        }
    });
    userChatBox.setBorder(new SoftBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, null, null));
    userChatBox.setTabSize(4);
    userChatBox.setLineWrap(true);
    userChatBox.setForeground(UIManager.getColor("ColorChooser.foreground"));
    userChatBox.setFont(new Font("DejaVu Serif", Font.PLAIN, 12));
    userChatBox.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    userChatBox.setBounds(10, 255, 400, 80);
    frmChatClient.getContentPane().add(userChatBox);
```

However, when the user presses enter, the JTextArea registers this as a return and enters a new line. Even after `userChatBox.setCaretPosition(0);`, the caret appears on the second line, and subsequently any string sent from the JTextArea will include a blank line. I have also tried setting the selection start and end with no avail.

Comment: I think [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32148769/4857909) will solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as @luxxminer said problem is  event occurs first before text append to jtextarea.if you can consume event ,then new line will not append.

so you can use `event.consume();` method

```
if (e.getKeyCode()==10){

    //If key pressed is enter.  
        client.send(userChatBox.getText());
        userChatBox.setCaretPosition(0);
        userChatBox.setText("");
        e.consume();
}
```

Comment: please is there real reason to use, why to use KeyListener for JTextComponents, maybe 10 == ENTER, this is a new_line as KeyBindings in the UIManager for JTextArea