# Why does my keyListener stop working when fullscreen?

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I have a key listener defined in the usual way:

```
frame.addKeyListener(this); 
frame.setFocusable(true);
```

And the methods to deal with the key press, which is when escape is hit the program exits.

This works but when I make the JFrame fill the whole window using:

```
frame.setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
frame.setLocation(0, 0);
frame.validate();
```

Then the key listener stops working. Could someone explain why this is and what I need to do when I go fullscreen to keep the listener?

TIA

Comment: don't use keyListeners, use keyBindings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> which is when escape is hit the program exits.

You would add [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to the root pane of your frame. Something like:

```
KeyStroke escapeKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ESCAPE");
Action escapeAction = new AbstractAction()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        // add code to end program
    }
};

getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(escapeKeyStroke, "ESCAPE");
getRootPane().getActionMap().put("ESCAPE", escapeAction);
```

Comment: There's a related example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7457102/230513) that demonstrates `setFullScreenWindow()` and key bindings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the KeyListener to a sub-component of the JFrame. When it goes full screen, I don't think the frame (which includes the title bar, close/maximize/minimize buttons, all of which are hidden in full screen) can receive input events.

Comment: Setting the size to the maximum screen size does not cause the title bar and border to be hidden.

Comment: Ah, I missed what he was referring to, and thought that he was using full-screen, not maximizing. :S