# Can I get the input and action map of a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, key-bindings

I've wanted to add a functionality to my program, if you press a specific key,the window will go fullscreen VIA KEYBINDINGS. And I tried `this.getInputMap()` and `this.getActionKey()`, but the JFrame does not have these methods.

Is there any way to use these methods within a JFrame, or are there any other methods, that are doing the same thing? Or should I use Key Listeners?

Comment: You should add the key bindings to the root pane of the frame. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8359296/131872 for a basic example.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.