# How Can A Program Close A GUI Without The Program Ending

Tags: java

Title says it all, before anyone says that there is a thread about closing a GUI without the program end then hold on a second.

My question is that, how can the PROGRAM close a GUI and not the user so it can progress onto another frame.

Comment: this should help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8632705/how-to-close-a-gui-when-i-push-a-jbutton

Comment: Didnt help since that terminates the entire running program with System.exit, then the dispose on close is used by the user.

Comment: woops, sorry that's my bad

Comment: Is this a Swing app -- your question is incomplete and never states this? Does your program have multiple windows open? Are you trying to close one JFrame while another stays open?

Comment: Would you mean close a GUI and open another one ? or downgrade to line mode in Unix like platforms ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.awt.Window aTopLevelGUI; // Normally referenced as a JWindow, but this is what impls setVisible(boolean)

// To close the window:
aTopLevelGUI.setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

If this question below is about a Swing GUI:

> My question is that, how can the PROGRAM close a GUI and not the user so it can progress onto another frame.

Then this question **can** be answered thusly:

- Set the JFrames default close operation property to `JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE`.
- A program can close any window by calling `close()` or `setVisible(false)` on the window.

i.e.,

```
myJFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

---

But having said that, the question in fact **should** be answered:

- Don't do this as this is a bad program design. No user wants windows flung at him.
- Instead have one main JFrame window open and rather than open and close windows, change **views** in the window by swapping JPanels, each holding its own simple or complex GUI.
- A [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) can help you do this easily.

---

Again, note that your question as originally stated is very incomplete, and in the future, you will want to tell us any and all relevant libraries that are involved, here the Swing library since the question is likely essentially a Swing question. You will also want to show some code and explain exactly where you might be stuck. Usually the better the question, the better the answers you'll see. For instance, with more information and code, we could show you some code to get you started with a CardLayout.