# JFrame Customization

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextarea

How to add some JtextField in title bar of JFrame..?
Or if I want to add some components in Title bar of Jframe 
Like there are tabs in Firefox 
*( although i know firefox is not made up in java competely )*

Comment: no i dont mean so i want to add some component where there is title of the jframe is shown...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `setUndecorated(true)` on `JFrame`s. Then you can implement your own titlebar which can be e.g. a tab bar like in Firefox or Chrome. But you need to take care for widgets for closing, moving, minimizing the window.

Comment: +1 for `setUndecorated()`; there's a related example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7457102/230513).

Answer (score 0):

When declaring your JFrame where I have "Test" put what you want the title of your JFrame to be.

```
Window = new JFrame("Test");
```