# setDefaultCloseOperation not working in Swing

Tags: java, swing, window, jdialog

I need to stop the default operation of window being closed when red x mark is clicked on the swing window. I am using the JDialog and adding WindowsListener to it to capture the WindowClosing event, there I decide whether to dispose JDialog or to not dispose it, I am also setting the following:

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
```

But still when I click on the red x mark, the window closes. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you paste some of your code to check it?

Comment: doNothingOnClose worksformealways - time to show an SSCCE

Comment: Hopefully this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9502882/how-to-turn-off-visible-of-x-button-and-disable-alt-f4-function/9503268#9503268) might help you :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding Window listener to the JDialog gave me the power to handle the window actions and I works fine in my application.

Comment: ehh ... this answer is very vague: no doubt it _can_ be done, the OP wants to know _how_ exactly to setup the dialog and _what_ exactly to do in the listener :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a WindowListener and do nothing when the close buttion is clicked.

```
jdialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() 
{
  public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e)
  {   
  }

  public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
  {
  }

});
```

Comment: Yes, this I am doing, but by default the behavior of the closing of the window is happening. To override the default behavior we need to do setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);, which I am doing, but it is still closing

Comment: the function you mentioned will work perfectly for jFrame. I'm not sure will it work for jDialog. Check the same.

Comment: -1 adding a do-nothing listener certainly has exactly ... zero effect (dialog or frame doesn't matter)

Comment: @Kleopatra It has zero effect. At the same time it wont close the window also.

Comment: the frame/dialog is closed by default :-)

Comment: @kleopatra it actually did an effect, I just needed to add an empty window listener and somehow it worked. `addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){});`