# Why are my buttons not visible in my JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, eclipse-plugin, fullscreen

I'm using the following code to create a fullscreen JFrame from my Eclipse plugin. The JFrame is shown, but I can't see my button. I have no idea why not:

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MainFrame() {
        super();

        createComponents();
        setFullScreen();

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void createComponents() {
        System.out.println("Create components");
        JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");

        exit.setVisible(true);
        exit.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        exit.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
        exit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                System.out.println("Exit by button");
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        this.setBackground(Color.RED);


        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.getContentPane().add(exit, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private void setFullScreen() {

        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setUndecorated(true);
        this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice[] devices = env.getScreenDevices();

        devices[0].setFullScreenWindow(this);
    }

}
```

Comment: works for me, just the button is the whole screen..

Comment: Have you tried to run it from a plugin?

Comment: The code works for mee, the button is the whole screen because of the layout. Try it with setLayout(null);

Comment: @dexametason Does it work for you if started from a Eclipse plugin=

Comment: @Roflcoptr Unfortunately I don't have any IDE in this computer, I executed it via command line.

Comment: Aren't Eclipse plugins supposed to be SWT-based, not Swing-based?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Could be, but I couldn't find a way to achieve a fullscreen window using SWT.

Answer (score 3):

For reference, [`FullScreenTest`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7457102/230513) is a working example.

Addendum: Because an Eclipse plugin must use SWT, you might try the approach shown in [*Full Screen your RCP Applications*](http://eclipse.dzone.com/tips/full-screen-your-rcp-applicati). The alternative of running maximized is also mentioned.

Comment: Yes I know that. But it is not working if I start it from my Eclipse plugin project. It works as a standalone application.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the plugin requirement; more above.