# Capturing keyboard combinations globally on the entire application to show hidden JDialog in Java

Tags: java, swing, global, keyboard-events

I'm going to make a hidden dialog in my application that get visible with a keyboard combination (e.g. Five sequent **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>**).
How Can I capture keyboard combination strokes globally on the entire application?

Thanks

Comment: You do know that a lot of keyboards will choke on more than two modifier keys being pressed simultaneously, right?

Comment: @thkala: No I don't! I never seen such a situation! but the count of modifiers is not important for me! I need only a combinations that be pressed number of sequent times (Even five Ctrl+a is acceptable!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by defining a `DispatcherListener`:

```
class DispatcherListener implements KeyEventDispatcher{
    private int level=0;

    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e) {
        if(e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED){
            if(e.isControlDown() && e.isShiftDown()){
                if(this.level==0 && e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_S){
                    level++;
                }else if(this.level==1 && e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_H){
                    level++;
                }else if(this.level==2 && e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_O){
                    level++;
                }else if(this.level==3 && e.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_W){
                    level=0;
                    this.showHiddenWindow((JFrame)SwingUtilities.getRoot(e.getComponent()));
                }else{
                    level=0;
                }

                //System.out.println( "level: " +  level );
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

and used it as this:

```
    KeyboardFocusManager manager = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager();
    manager.addKeyEventDispatcher( new DispatcherListener());
```

Thank you all

Answer (score 2):

[`FullScreenTest`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7457102/230513) is an example that shows how to use `Action` and [*Key Bindings*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) in this context. You could substitute `KeyEvent.VK_I` and the relevant `KeyStroke` modifiers. Your action listener can keep count of how often it's been triggered.