# How Would I Make An ActionListener Listen To A Key Press?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

My code simply displays a random colour and has a button to get a new one but how could I make the `ActionListener` respond to pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> as well?

Also, how can I make the button not fill the whole width of the `JFrame`?

Here is my code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class RandomColour {

    public static JFrame frame;

    public static Color[] colours = {Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.ORANGE, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.BLACK, Color.MAGENTA, Color.CYAN, Color.PINK,};

    public static int random;

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        random = (int)(Math.random()*(9)+0);

        JButton button = new JButton ("New Random Colour");

        button.setSize(10, 10);

        frame = new JFrame ("Random Colour");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(6,6,6,6));

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.getContentPane().setBackground(colours[(int)(Math.random()*(9)+0)]);
            }
        });


        panel.add(button);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(colours[random]);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*Fire a JButton with spacebar, or enter key, or mouse click*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10710748/230513), which illustrates `setDefaultButton()`.

Answer (score 1):

The button is already supposed to react to the Enter keypress but i**t needs to be set as the default button for your frame and it needs to have the focus**, so add the following two lines to your code and it will work as you are expecting it to:

```
frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(button);
button.requestFocus();
```

The more detailed illustration below:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class RandomColour {
    public static JFrame frame;

    public static Color[] colours = {Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.ORANGE, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.BLACK, Color.MAGENTA, Color.CYAN, Color.PINK,};

    public static int random;

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        random = (int)(Math.random()*(9)+0);

        JButton button = new JButton ("New Random Colour");

        button.setSize(10, 10);

        frame = new JFrame ("Random Colour");
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,2));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,2));

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                frame.getContentPane().setBackground(colours[(int)(Math.random()*(9)+0)]);
            }
        });

        panel.add(button);

        // The changes are the next two lines
        frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(button);
        button.requestFocus();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(colours[random]);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
}
```

Swing uses layout manager to handle components presentations and arrangement for you, **if you want more flexibility you should consider using the GridBagLayout** ( [Example here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/swing_gridbaglayout.htm)) **or design more complexe layout by combining existing layout managers** (such as the default BorderLayoutManager with GridLayout for example)

Answer (score 0):

So you have 2 options,

you can either copy the entire action listener code you already wrote and add it to the enter button the same way.

OR...

You can make the action listener into a named object (example)

```
ActionListener thing = new ActionListener(...)
```

then

```
button.addActionListener(thing)
enterbutton.addActionListener(thing)
```

will stick the same one onto both.

Comment: How would I make the action listener use the enter button?