# Fullscreen possibilities?

Tags: java, swing, awt, jpanel, fullscreen

I am finding it hard to convert my JPanel into a lwjgl fullscreen display? is there another way or a guide on what you need to change:

This is what i am currently calling it with:

```
public void TowerDefence() {
    setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 0, 0));

    Window window = new Window(this);
    add(window);

    setVisible(true);
}
```

And this is what is called to initialize the JPanel:

```
public Window(Frame frame) {
    frame.addMouseListener(new KeyHandler());
    frame.addMouseMotionListener(new KeyHandler());

    thread.start();
}
```

Do i need to change only inside this constructor? And what needs to be added in order for fullscreen to work?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your best attempt.

Answer (score 1):

See the lesson on the [Full-Screen Exclusive Mode API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/index.html) in the tutorial.

Comment: Could you provide an example? I don't understand the documentation and when i try it it doesn't work?

Comment: What I could provide is irrelevant, since I don't intend to.  Show some effort, post an SSCCE, and I might look further into it.  Also note that "doesn't work" is about as useful as a screen-door on a submarine at describing the actual problem.  What did you expect to happen?  What actually happened?

Comment: [`FullScreenTest`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7457102/230513) may help you create your SSCCE.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

Comment: What operation system is the code running on? I think there are some platforms on which this method is not supported... take a look the javadocs for this method