# limit JavaSwing application size to screen size?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

My application is currently too large for the `window(monitor)`. I've built a scrollbar into the application to accommodate it but it still extends over the window rather than use the scrollbar. Originally, the initialization of the outer frame calls `pack()`, then `setVisible(true)`.

I've tried to set the size of the frame but it doesn't seem to have an effect. The outer frame is a Masthead, and I call `getWindow()` on it to set size. Calling `mframe.getWindow().setSize(640, 480);` doesn't do anything.

This is the current behavior: 
[image]

This is what I'd like: 
[image]

EDIT: what's a good way for setting the app to full screen on startup?

Comment: And if you try `mframe.setSize(x,y)`?

Comment: [`FullScreenTest`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7457102/230513) may be a useful [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Are you looking for `setExtendedState()` or `setFullScreenWindow()`?

Comment: I didn't think you could change the size of the "window" in full screen mode.  You need to look at the size of you components instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've tried to set the size of the frame but it doesn't seem to have an effect.

That's because you called pack on the window. `pack()` sets the component's size to be the maximum of an components it contains, which makes your `setSize()` useless.

From the api:

> `pack()` Causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents.

Comment: i took pack() out before setSize(). I'm just saying it was there before.

Comment: Why would `pack` stop `setSize` from working in the future?  Sorry if that's not what you meant, but that's how I read it.  If you `setSize` then `pack`, yes your right, otherwise I'm confused... :P

Comment: i don't use pack at all anymore. But even if I try to chnage the dimensions of the frame, nothing seems to happen. I tried to setSize() and i tried to set it to fullsize: mframe.getWindow().setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want to use [Toolkit#getScreenSize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#getScreenSize%28%29) combined with [setSize](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setSize%28int,%20int%29). Something like (for example, to set it to a specific percentage of screen size):

```
Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
component.setSize((int)(screenSize.width * widthPercent),
                  (int)(screenSize.height * heightPercent));
```

If you want your app to start maximized, you might want to look at [setExtendedState](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState%28int%29), like

```
myFrame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```