# Frame doesn't show in full-screen

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, fullscreen, paint

I have a problem with full-screen : i create a frame and put it in a full-screen Window but i see nothing but the color of the frame's background.

here is the code i used:

```
PB frame = new PB();

win = new Window(frame);

gs.setFullScreenWindow(win);

frame.setVisible(true);
frame.repaint();

win.repaint();
```

and the PB class, my frame:

```
 public class PB extends JFrame
{
    PB()
    {
        super();
        this.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        this.getContentPane().add(new JButton("button"));
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        jp.setBackground(Color.red);
        jp.setSize(360, 200);
        this.getContentPane().add(jp);
        this.setVisible(true);
        repaint();
        pack();
    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setPaint(new Color(0,0,0));
        g.fillRect(0,0,200,200);
    }
}
```

So all i can see, is a big screen with the background color (here blue);

Thanks for all help

Comment: Fro reference, a working [sscce](http://sscce.org/) may be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7457102/230513).

Comment: The frame does show in full screen, you just only paint a colored rectangle in it...

Comment: thank you very much!! the sscce got me out of the pit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet you didn't try your frame separately, did you?

This part of frame code:

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.setPaint(new Color(0,0,0));
    g.fillRect(0,0,200,200);
}
```

will never let it paint its own content, just the colored rect.

So my recomendations are:

1. Do not override JFrame's paint method - it will cause a lot of problems
2. Just set main container panel background to the desired color
3. Try the frame without full-screen window first to see if it displays what you need

Answer (score 2):

I think you're mis-understading the purpose of the "owner" for the `Window`.

`JFrame` extends from `Window`.

So, instead of saying

```
win = new Window(frame);
gs.setFullScreenWindow(win);
```

You only need to use

```
gs.setFullScreenWindow(frame);
```

Oh, and what Mikle said as well.