# SwingUtilities.invokeLater : Issues

Tags: java, swing, swingutilities, invokelater

I never understood `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`,that is the reason i kept avoiding it until now.But its very important to make Swing Thread safe.
Well please excuse me, as this is my first time with this.
I am trying to Close the window after some data base query.So,as far as i understood,
any updation in `UI` must be handled by `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`.Here is my work:

Main:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
    new forminsert().setVisible(true);
forminsert f=new forminsert();
    }
    });

    }
  public forminsert() {
    initComponents();
}

public class forminsert extends javax.swing.JFrame {    
private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setUndecorated(true);

    jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
    jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(3, 3, 3, 3, new java.awt.Color(0, 204, 204)));
              /////***REST CODE***/////           

}
```

listner on ADD button

```
  private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)               {                                         
 new Thread(new thread1()).start();

}                                        
public class thread1 implements Runnable
{

    public void run() {
     insert ins=new insert();
    ////code for inserting///     
    }
 }
```

listner on browse button

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                {                                         
    JFileChooser ss=new JFileChooser();
    ////Code to choose the file////
                 }
```

here is the problem,code to exit.

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

forminsert f=new forminsert();f.call();
}

public  void call()
{
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
 jPanel1.setVisible(false);
getRootPane().setVisible(false);

    }
    });
```

Screen:
[image: screen short]

Please explain me where i am going wrong,i dont want to use `System.exit` and excuse me for asking too many questions.Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

Here is a sample **working** code as requested by @trashgod

```
package faltur;

import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;

public class insert extends javax.swing.JFrame {

/** Creates new form insert */
public insert() {
    initComponents();
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

 private void initComponents() {

    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setUndecorated(true);

    jPanel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(240, 240, 240));

    jButton1.setText("Browse..");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setText("exit");
    jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
    jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
    jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 185, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(153, 153, 153)
                    .addComponent(jButton2)))
            .addContainerGap(99, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(66, 66, 66)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addGap(87, 87, 87)
            .addComponent(jButton2)
            .addContainerGap(94, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,   javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );

    pack();
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                {                                         
 JFileChooser ss=new JFileChooser();
 ss.showOpenDialog(jTextField1);

 File f=ss.getSelectedFile();

   path=f.toString();
    System.out.println(path);

}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
  insert in=new insert();
  in.exit();/////////////CALLS exit()/////////////////modify this//////
}


public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new insert().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
public void exit()////////////////////////MODIFY THIS///////////////////
{
jPanel1.getRootPane().setVisible(false);

}

private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;

 public String path="";
}
```

Please run and tell how to modify `exit()` so that it closes the window.Thanks once again.

Comment: For starters, why **don't you** use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` there?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik where exactly?

Comment: At the point you use `invokeLater`.

Comment: Please start Classnames with a Capital. And why do you create new instances of `forminsert` all the time?

Comment: You can understand Swing and threads better after reading this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik i am using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`inside Main also

Comment: You clearly aren't. In fact, the class `SwingUtilities` is not referenced anywhere in your code.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: As of 1.3 this method is just a cover for `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater()`.

Comment: @trashgod That should be left to the implementation. Code should be written against `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik same method on EventQueue _is_ referenced

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik wont `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater` will do more or less the same thing?

Comment: invokeLater is not the major malfunction here ...

Comment: It **may** do the same and it definitely does the same on certain implementations. However, it is not idiomatic to write your code against that method directly. It's even more confusing that you consistently refer to `SwingUtilties` in your question, but not in your code.

Comment: darn, @trashgod beat me by a full half-minute :-) Curious, why would you (@Marko) would prefer SwingUtilities? Don't see any reason to not follow the doc.

Comment: @trashgod last time i used component hidden to close the window,more or less the same.

Comment: In the shown code you also copied the Constructor of `forminsert` to a wrong place, I guess ... I really think the main problem is the creation of new instances of the form rather than the correct version of invokelater.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I agree that using both `EventQueue` and `SwingUtilities` in same the question is confusing. I'd encourage consistency, modulo [Emerson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-Reliance). :-)

Comment: @trashgod In fairness, Emerson had something else in mind, but still, I appreciate the reference :) Even though, after re-reading the javadoc for `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`, I can agree that it is a documented fact that these are the same, the fact remains that the question confuses gratuitously.

Comment: +1 for [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your frame's default close operation is `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`, you can send `WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING` via `dispatchEvent()`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7457102/230513). Given a `JFrame f`,

```
private static final String EXIT = "Exit";
private Action exit = new AbstractAction(EXIT) {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            f.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(
                f, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
        }
    };
private JButton b = new JButton(exit);
```

See also [*How to Use Actions*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) and follow common [coding conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

Addendum: Based on the revised code, here is one approach to *exiting* the program. Note class names typically start with a capital letter, while instance names are lower case.

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    insert.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(
        insert, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            insert = new Insert();
            insert.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

private static Insert insert;
...
```

Comment: why getRootPane().setVisible(false) it not working in my code?

Comment: I don't see that you need `getRootPane()`, except maybe to call `setDefaultButton()`; and you don't need `invokeLater()`, of any provenance, in the `Action`. If you still have problems, please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

Well insted of using `foo.setVisible(false)`,
simply i changed it to `setVisible(false)`, and it worked.

Comment: Am I correct that you didn't want to exit the program, just close the window?

Comment: @trashgod yup otherwise would have used System.exit

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. I thought you wanted to avoid `System.exit()` because it abruptly bypasses listeners, etc.