# Execute JButton when ENTER key is pressed in panel - Swing

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, keyevent

I have <kbd>Login</kbd> `JButton` on a panel and I need to execute it when I press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key.

Do we have any code snippet for that?

Comment: *"Do we have any code snippet for that?"*  Do we have any sign of effort on we's part?  Or is we just treating SO as a code factory?

Comment: See [How to use Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html#setDefaultButton%28javax.swing.JButton%29

Comment: @JBNizet  As I was musing over the wisdom of your link, I was thinking how it would be great if there was a [stack app](http://stackapps.com/) to automatically translate such links to links with text constructed as follows. Fetch the page title `JRootPane (Java Platform SE 7 )` append 
`: ` + (the link text)
`setDefaultButton`

To appear as
**`JRootPane (Java Platform SE 7 ): setDefaultButton`**.  If I get around tuit, I must see if I can get something together that is workable.  I think it would need to maintain a local cache of titles and and anchor texts, which might be problematic..

Comment: Or.. [JRootPane (Java Platform SE 7 ): setDefaultButton](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html#setDefaultButton%28javax.swing.JButton%29). At the end of the last comment there were 7 chars spare, not enough to add the actual link!

Comment: Lots of efforts to deal with my laziness :) My comments usually show an effort that is proportional to the effort put in the commented question...

Comment: @JBNizet  LOL!  ;)  Actually I think the brevity of it adds to the charm of the comment.  Straight to the point.  :)

Comment: Also consider `setDefaultButton()`, seen [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7457102/230513).

Comment: Apologies for the vague question! My intention is to create a keylistener kind of thing for a Jbutton, which executes when I press the ENTER key. I just saw the action map and I hope it'll solve my issue. Let me implement and revert back. Thanks for sharing the solutions though.

Answer (score 2):

To have initial focus on your button you can do something like this:

```
frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(buttonName);
buttonName.requestFocus();
```

---

//Or you can bind your `Enter` key to `JComponent` and `JButton` as:

```
AbstractAction action = new AbstractAction() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() instanceof JButton){
        JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
        button.doClick();        
        } else if(e.getSource() instanceof JComponent){
            JComponent component = (JComponent) e.getSource();
            component.transferFocus();
        }
    }
    };
```

//You can bind key to JComponent like:

```
jComponent.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "TransferFocus");
jComponent.getActionMap().put("TransferFocus", action);
```

//You can bind key to JButton like:

```
jButton.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER, 0), "DoClick");
jButton.getActionMap().put("DoClick", action);
```

---

**Useful Link**

[How to Use the Focus Subsystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `InputMap` and `ActionMap` to do this.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
class ac1
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    JFrame f=new JFrame();
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setSize(400,400);
    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    final JButton b=new JButton("button");
    f.add(b);



f.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDO

W).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER,0),"clickButton");

f.getRootPane().getActionMap().put("clickButton",new AbstractAction(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
        {
    b.doClick();
    System.out.println("button clicked");
        }
    });
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer...Thanks....