# How to close child jFrames automatically when i close the parent?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a parent JFrame and two 'child' JFrames in package JFrame. Imagine I open parent JFrame and then it's child JFrames - currently all 3 forms are open.  Now I close parent JFrame.

What should I do to close all child frames automatically after close their parent JFrame?
Here is my code:

class Parent:
public class Parent extends JFrame {

```
public Parent() {

    JButton child1 = new JButton("child1");
    child1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new Child1().setVisible(true);;
        }
    });

    JButton child2 = new JButton("child2");
    child2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new Child2().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
    JButton closeAllJframe = new JButton("closeAllJframe");
    closeAllJframe.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            dispose();
        }
    });

    this.setBounds(500, 200, 400, 200);
    this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
            dispose();
        }
    });
    JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
    jPanel.add(child1);
    jPanel.add(child2);
    jPanel.add(closeAllJframe);
    this.add(jPanel);
}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Parent().setVisible(true);
}}
```

class Child1:

public class Child1 extends JFrame  {

```
public Child1() {
    this.setBounds(200, 300, 300, 200);
    this.setTitle("child 1");
}}
```

class Child2:

public class Child2 extends JFrame  {

```
public Child2() {
    this.setBounds(200, 300, 300, 200);
    this.setTitle("child 1");
}}
```

Comment: forms?do you mean jframes?

Comment: if it's jframes, then add window listener and call dispose on child jframes on window closing event.

Comment: 1) Tip: Add @FastSnail (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) Tip: The 'child frames' whould be dialogs instead.

Comment: @FastSnail: Yes,i do. can you explain more? thanks.

Comment: *"Are you with me?"* I got notified of the new comment, if that's what you mean..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*How to close multiple JFrame and JDialog windows?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28008652/230513)

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I carelessly voted to close ethics as _unclear what you're asking_, but it may be a duplicate.

Comment: @SajadNasiriNezhad: If this is _not_ a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your current approach.

Comment: child frames? There is no childhood in between frame in Swing. Be more precise... Describe exactly what's inside you UI.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès *"Describe exactly what's inside you UI."* An MCVE/SSCCE is superb for doing just that.

Answer (score 0):

Add an window listener to the frame then implements the `windowClosed(WindowEvent e)` method [Javadoc about WindowListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html)