# How to listen to keypress events in a jdialog container?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans

I have a JDialog that contains many rows of textfields and a submit button. I would like to know if it's possible to add an eventListener to the container to trigger the submit button.

Comment: Looks like a palce for KeyBinding's usage

Comment: can you explain your question in more detail so that I can understand better what you actually want to do

Comment: For better help sooner, please add a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates the issue you have. Furthermore, it is difficult to tell what exactly you want to do; it may even be that listening to key presses might not be the right approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One convenient way to bind <kbd>Enter</kbd> to an [`Action`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) is via the root pane's [`setDefaultButton()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JRootPane.html#setDefaultButton-javax.swing.JButton-) method. You can also use the `Action` in a [key binding](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html), as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7457102/230513).

```
JDialog d = new JDialog(…);
Action submit = new AbstractAction("Submit") {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // handle submit
    }
};
private JButton b = new JButton(submit);
…
d.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(button);
    // removing the binding for pressed
    frame.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)
        .put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ENTER"), "none");
    // retarget the binding for released
    frame.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)
        .put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("released ENTER"), "press");
```

Or else do something like the following

```
 addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){  
       @Override
       public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke)
       {
       if (e.getKeyCode().equals(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER))
         { 
      //copy paste the logic you wrote inside the ActionPerformed method
         }
      }});

      setFocusable(true);//Setting Focus true for ur container

      requestFocusInWindow();//Requesting the focus. Without this, KeyEvent will not trigger on your container
```

Comment: Object as JFrame is by default doesn't react to KeyEvents from KeyListener

Comment: I was dicey, hence i provided both the options mate