# Change AWT Frame's maximize behaviour to fullscreen on MacOS

Tags: java, macos, swing, jvm, awt

When creating an AWT `Frame` in a Java program running on MacOS, the maximize button in the frame's title bar maximises the window:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Frame();
}
```

When I create a Swing `JFrame` instance instead, the same button toggles the window into fullscreen mode, which is the standard behaviour on MacOS. The button even looks different visually when I hover over it:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    new JFrame();
}
```

Is there any way how I can replicate JFrame's "maximize to fullscreen" behaviour with AWT's Frame? I scanned the code of the entire JFrame class and wasn't able to identify any logic that would toggle the Frame's behaviour in such a way.

Comment: You may be able to leverage the `com.apple.eawt` methods mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30308671/230513), but I haven't tried.

Comment: Why use AWT in this day & age?

Comment: I want something that’s light-weight and as simple as possible as I only need a window with a canvas. Everything else will happen through Java2D and I don’t see why I need all the baggage of Swing for opening a simple window.

Comment: I tried using `com.apple.eawt` via reflection and I get the following `java.lang.IllegalAccessException`:
`cannot access class com.apple.eawt.FullScreenUtilities (in module java.desktop) because module java.desktop does not export com.apple.eawt to unnamed module @57fffcd7`

Comment: @tyrondis: AFAIK, Java 8 was the last SDK with full support; Java 11 lost `QuitStrategy`, and Java 17 has none; for reference, the example links to the source; also consider `setUndecorated()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.Window;

public class MyFrame extends Frame {

    MyFrame() {
        for (Window w : Window.getWindows()) {
            GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
                    .getDefaultScreenDevice().setFullScreenWindow(w);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyFrame f = new MyFrame();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: This code launches my window full-screen, however, I want a `Frame` to have the same "maximise to fullscreen" button a `JFrame` window has and act accordingly.

Comment: Sorry, thats not possible.