# Java Swing Mac OSX Preferences Menu

Tags: java, macos, swing, menu, preferences

I'm trying to add the Preferences menu to my Java Swing application and it's proving a bit of a nause.

I have read many posts and articles on this and it sounds easy but...

I see references to **com.apple.eawt.Application** in the examples I have found but when I try to import it in **Eclipse Indigo** I get an error:
*Access restriction: The type Application is not accessible due to restriction on required library /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Classes/ui.jar*

Any ideas?

I am working on an iMac OSX 10.6

Comment: Please cite whichever of the "many posts and articles" you think may guide responders.

Comment: Here's an example of an article about adding the 'Preferences Menu': http://www.devdaily.com/java/java-mac-osx-about-preferences-quit-application-adapter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be able to use [`OSXAdapter`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/samplecode/OSXAdapter/Introduction/Intro.html), which "uses a reflection proxy model to hook existing preferences, about, and quit functionality." See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2061318/230513).