# Swing Dialog not visible but it is active

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jdialog

my application has a section in which a list of several items gets displayed on left. If a user selects any item, the details of that item gets displayed on right inside a JPANEL.
Now at the bottom of this JPANEL we have a button to delete this item.

ISSUE REPORTED: Some user have reported that when they click on "delete button", they are not able to see the delete pop up box( which is a JDIALOG). Delete Dialog has two buttons : cancel n ok. by default, the focus is on "cancel" button.

MY CONCERN : When user clicks "tab key" and press enter, that item gets deleted. This shows that though the JDIALOG is not visible but it is active and is working fine.

Now, this issue comes very rarely, and not always. I am not able to find out the root cause of this issue and what is the thing that is causing it??? 95 percent it works fine and 5 percent it gives this problem.

Has anyone faced issue like this before, or have any ideas on how to resolve it??
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you be able to post a working code snippet, or just paste the class(es) in general?

Comment: In your [mcve], include version information, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2061318/230513).

Comment: @Gorbhles Sir, We are not allowed to post our project code online and also  the code base for this requirement is too large which I cannot put here. I can provide you version information: we are using java 7.  I am looking for experience here...