# How to intercept Cmd+Q

Tags: macos

I am working on Win/MacOS game app.
When user closes the app, I want to show a confirmation popup sorta "Are you sure you want to leave?".

On Windows, I listen to `WM_CLOSE` message to intercept *Alt-F4*. Then, if user selects "Yes, I want to leave" -- I call `PostQuitMessage(0);` to exit the app.

How do I intercept *Cmd+Q* on Mac OS? And, if user selects "Yes, I want to leave" -- how do I close the app (i.e. how to perform the same action as *Cmd+Q* does by default)?

MacOS part is in written in plain Objective-C and I am looking for an answer in Objective-C.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swing on OSX: How to Trap command-Q?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061194/swing-on-osx-how-to-trap-command-q)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement the delegate method `applicationShouldTerminate` of `NSApplication` and show a custom modal alert. Depending on the answer return `NSTerminateNow`, `NSTerminateCancel` or `NSTerminateLater`.

In case of `NSTerminateLater` you can later call `[NSApp replyToApplicationShouldTerminate:YES];` to finally quit the app.