# JFrame DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE is not working on Command + Q

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am creating a window that I need to close it by **only** clicking a button. 
For that I'm using 
**setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE)**  mehod.


But the problem is my Mac is closing that window when I click <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd>.

Here is a code:

```
package screen.saver;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

public class ScreenSaver {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());

        JFrame screenSaverFrame = new JFrame();
        screenSaverFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        screenSaverFrame.setUndecorated(true);
        screenSaverFrame.setResizable(false);

        JButton closeWindow = new JButton("Close window");
        closeWindow.addActionListener(e -> {
            screenSaverFrame.dispose();
        });

        screenSaverFrame.add(closeWindow, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        screenSaverFrame.validate();
        GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
                .getDefaultScreenDevice()
                .setFullScreenWindow(screenSaverFrame);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"But the problem is my Mac is closing that window when I click command + q"* - Yes, that's how it works, CMD+Q is terminating the process

Comment: But I don't what it to be closed by command + q. I want to close it only by button

Comment: Why? What did your users do to you?

Comment: I just want to lock my screen every 30 minutes for making breaks.

Comment: I would suggest having a look at `  Application.getApplication().setQuitStrategy(QuitStrategy.CLOSE_ALL_WINDOWS);` and `Application.getApplication().disableSuddenTermination();` - see [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061194/swing-on-osx-how-to-trap-command-q) for more details

Comment: *"I just want to lock my screen every 30 minutes for making breaks"* - This won't stop you, because you could CMD+Tab to get to other processes

Comment: It won't switch to another application by cmd + Tab. I have already checked it. )) It is only reacting on cmd + q

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061194/swing-on-osx-how-to-trap-command-q). It worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple provides a couple of useful APIs.  Start by having a look at [Java for OS X v10.6 Update 3 and 10.5 Update 8 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/Java/JavaSnowLeopardUpdate3LeopardUpdate8RN/NewandNoteworthy/NewandNoteworthy.html) and [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061194/swing-on-osx-how-to-trap-command-q) for more details.

In particular, what you're really interested in

> ## Sudden Termination
>
> Java applications on OS X v10.6 can now opt-in to being suddenly terminated by the OS to speed log-out and shut down.
> Apps can raise and lower their sudden termination count with the
> enableSuddenTermination() and disableSuddenTermination() methods on
> the com.apple.eawt.Application class. More information on Sudden
> Termination is available in NSProcessInfo Class Reference. (5756768)
>
> ## Default Quit Action
>
> Applications can now request that the eAWT send WindowClosing events to all open windows instead of calling
> System.exit(0) when the user choose Quit from the application menu. By
> setting the apple.eawt.quitStrategy system property to
> CLOSE_ALL_WINDOWS, the eAWT will send a close event to every window in
> back-to-front order (3198576).

This should allow you to better control how the app is terminated, for example...

```
import com.apple.eawt.Application;
import com.apple.eawt.FullScreenUtilities;
import com.apple.eawt.QuitStrategy;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.getApplication().setQuitStrategy(QuitStrategy.CLOSE_ALL_WINDOWS);
        Application.getApplication().disableSuddenTermination();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setUndecorated(true);
                FullScreenUtilities.setWindowCanFullScreen(frame, true);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                JButton close = new JButton("Close me");
                close.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        frame.dispose();
                    }
                });
                frame.add(close);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("Closed");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("Closing");
                    }

                });
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                //Application.getApplication().requestToggleFullScreen(frame);
                //frame.setVisible(true);
                GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
                                .getDefaultScreenDevice()
                                .setFullScreenWindow(frame);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When pressing <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>, the `windowClosing` event is triggered, meaning the only way to terminate the app is tap the close button

## Java 9

It should be noted that, for those people lucky enough to be using it, Java 9 adds much of the support which was previously found in `com.apple.eawt` to the API via the [`java.awt.Desktop`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html) API

Comment: By the way, how about other OS

Comment: If you want run it on other os’s, you’ll need to use reflection to make it work (as it’ll crash otherwise). Using DO_NOTHING “should” work on Windows, but you’ll have to test it